# R shinydashboard Number of Rows in Table derived from slider input

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to have a data table created in R shinydashboard that has 2 columns and X number of rows based on sliderInput values. This is challenging because I need every element in the data table to be editable by the user, and then once the user has filled out all elements, they can hit an action button to save this new data table to an object to have future computations done.

The code below has 3 tabs, however I'm focused on just getting the first to work for now (tabName = "2int").

To populate a data table with two columns and "obs1" number of rows, I'm using the matrix function and having all cells contain NA, however (1) it is having a hard time reading the number of rows from the input "obs1" saying it's not in the reactive environment, and (2)not sure the best way to make this table editable with integers 1:5 step = 1 and subsequently saved.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Interview Reliability"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Two Interviewers",
               tabName = "2int",
               icon = icon("glass-whiskey")),
      menuItem("Three Interviewers",
               tabName = "3int",
               icon = icon("glass-whiskey")),
      menuItem("Four Interviewers",
               tabName = "4int",
               icon = icon("glass-whiskey"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "2int",
            fluidRow(box(sliderInput("obs1", "Number of Interview Questions:",
                            value = 4,
                            min = 4,
                            max = 12,
                            step = 1))),
            box(dataTableOutput("table1")),
            box(actionButton("sub", "Submit Number of Interview Questions", icon("Submit"), style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))
            ),
    
      tabItem(tabName = "3int",
              box(sliderInput("obs2", "Number of Interview Questions:",
                              value = 4,
                              min = 4,
                              max = 12,
                              step = 1))
              
            ),
    
      tabItem(tabName = "4int",
              box(sliderInput("obs3", "Number of Interview Questions:",
                              value = 4,
                              min = 4,
                              max = 12,
                              step = 1)),
      )
            
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  tableValues <- reactiveValues(df = matrix(NA, nrow = input$obs1, ncol = 2,
                                            dimnames = list(1:input$obs1, c("Interviewer 1", "Interviewer 2"))))
 
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      tableValues$df
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have looked at numerous tutorials and rshiny resources but have not been able to find anything that covers this particular combination of functionality. Apologize for the multi-part question. Knowing the end goal is to have the data table editable and saved to an object was pertinent to addressing the issue of generating the data table with correct row numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should address your two issues.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  tableValues <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$obs1, {
    tableValues$df <- matrix(NA, nrow = input$obs1, ncol = 2,
                             dimnames = list(1:input$obs1, c("Interviewer 1", "Interviewer 2")))
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT(tableValues$df, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', editable=TRUE) 
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I now want to pass my table1 with the edited elements to the `agree` function. I added `box(verbatimTextOutput("irr1"))` to my tab1 specificiations in my UI, and added `output$irr1 <- renderPrint(table1$df) %>% agree()` to my sever specifications but am getting an error saying "can't find table1". Any ideas how to pass the table once it has been edited to the `agree()` function?

Comment: Perhaps you should post it as a separate question with the code on what you have tried.  SO is not meant to have too many follow-up questions.  Each question will be answered by someone who has some free time.

Comment: Thank you - posted in new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69453661/r-shinydashboard-pass-reactive-table-to-function-to-be-printed-via-action-button